# Use context.router.replace without rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have redundant rerendering issue where it caused my app to flicked. The culprit is in the context.router.replace

```
handleTabChanged = (tabId, key) => {
    this.setState({
        selectedTabId: tabId
    }, () => {
        //change query of browser url
        this.context.router.replace({
            pathname: `/applications/${this.props.app_id}`,
            query: { status:this.state.selectedTabId }
        });
    });

    //ajax call;
}
```

Is there anyway to change path but don't rerender? I comment out context.router.replace it's ok, but I have to change the path, any clue?

Comment: You want to change what's in the addressbar without *actually* being redirected or having anything re-rendered? Also, explain *why* you want this, I don't see why you would want this.

Comment: @Chris I want to change the url, but i got few times of rerender, I comment out the router.replace, my application won't flick, any clue?

Comment: Is it not expected that the page will re-render if you change the URL? You have to explain **in detail** and **why** you want to do this. What is the URL, is it to another website or within the same React app?